# put Activity into Tablayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I have this activity with some adapters , I would put it in tableLayout I already try some methods ,

unfortunately they didn't work , ( extends FragmentActivity , Convert Activity to Fragment with using onCreateView() )

```
`public class MainActivity_Delete extends AppCompatActivity` {

private SwipeMenuListView listView;
private ArrayList<Data> dataArrayList;
private ListAdapter listAdapter;
private Data data;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_delete);

    listView = (SwipeMenuListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    dataArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    listAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, dataArrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    listView.setMenuCreator(creator);

    listView.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new SwipeMenuListView.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(int position, SwipeMenu menu, int index) {
            switch (index) {
                case 0:

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity_Delete.this, "Delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e("item", String.valueOf(listView.getAdapter().getItem(position)));
                    Log.e("name", String.valueOf(dataArrayList.get(position).getName()));

                    dataArrayList.remove(position);

                    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    break;
                case 1:
                    // delete
                    break;
            }
            // false : close the menu; true : not close the menu
            return false;
        }
    });

}

SwipeMenuCreator creator = new SwipeMenuCreator() {
    @Override
    public void create(SwipeMenu menu) {


        // create "delete" item
        SwipeMenuItem deleteItem = new SwipeMenuItem(
                getApplicationContext());
        // set item background
        deleteItem.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#F45557")));
        // set item width
        deleteItem.setWidth(150);

        deleteItem.setTitle("Delete");
        deleteItem.setTitleColor(Color.WHITE);
        deleteItem.setTitleSize(15);

        // add to menu
        menu.addMenuItem(deleteItem);
    }
};
```

}

Comment: Unclear what you asking

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I want to add this activity into a tabLayout

Comment: using Fragments is the best option

Answer (score 0):

There is `android.app.ActivityGroup` but this class has been deprecated since API level 13. So, in essence you cannot embed an activity in another activity. You can reuse layout files, however. See [Re-using Layouts with <include/>](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) The best option is, of course, to make use of fragments. They are the standard for such things.

Comment: Thank you ,I know that include for xml but my problem related to java class could you give me some explanation